OnKeyPress not triggered in DevExpress component descendant
The code below defines a TcxDBBlobEdit descendantwith its own OnKeyPress.
My issue is that this OnKeyPress ('breakpoint here') never gets triggered.
What am I overlooking?
type
  TPasswordTcxDBBlobEdit = class(TcxDBBlobEdit)    // DevExpress component
  private
    procedure SetPasswordMode(const Value: Boolean);
  protected
     FPasswordMode : Boolean;
     FPasswordChar : Char;
     FPrivateKeyFld: String;
     procedure WMPaste(var Message: TWMPaste); message WM_PASTE;
  public
     property PasswordMode: Boolean read FPasswordMode write SetPasswordMode;
     property PasswordChar: Char write FPasswordChar;
     property PrivateKeyFld: String write FPrivateKeyFld;
     constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
     procedure KeyPress(var Key: Char); override; Key: Char); override;
  end;

{ TPasswordTcxDBBlobEdit }

constructor TPasswordTcxDBBlobEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
   inherited;
   FPasswordMode := false;
   FPasswordChar := '*';
end;

procedure TPasswordTcxDBBlobEdit.KeyPress(var Key: Char);
var
   lCtrl,
   lShift,
   lPaste: Boolean;
begin
   if not FPasswordMode then Exit;  // <-- Breakpoint here
   lCtrl  := (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0); // High bit set
   lShift := (GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0);
   lPaste := lCtrl and ((Key = 'V') or (Key = 'v') or (Key = #$16))   // #$16 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78928063/weird-16-value-for-v-character-in-onkeypress
             or
             lShift and (GetKeyState(VK_INSERT) < 0);
   if not lPaste then
      Key := #0;

  inherited;
end;

The new component is created in the FormCreate:
procedure TDialoogEditProvider.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   FEditFTPPrivateKey := TPasswordTcxDBBlobEdit.Create(nil);   // Before inherited because this assigns FEditFTPPrivateKey.DataBinding.DataSource/DataField
   
   FEditFTPPrivateKey.PasswordMode := true;                   
   FEditFTPPrivateKey.Parent       := PanelFTP;
   FEditFTPPrivateKey.Properties.BlobEditKind                   := bekMemo;
   FEditFTPPrivateKey.Properties.BlobPaintStyle                 := bpsText;
   FEditFTPPrivateKey.Properties.ImmediateDropDownWhenActivated := False;
   FEditFTPPrivateKey.TabOrder     := ComboFTPType.TabOrder + 1;
   FEditFTPPrivateKey.Width        := ComboFTPType.Width;
   FEditFTPPrivateKey.Height       := ComboFTPType.Height;
   FEditFTPPrivateKey.Left         := ComboFTPType.Left;
   FEditFTPPrivateKey.Top          := ComboFTPType.Top + ComboFTPType.Height + 4;
   FEditFTPPrivateKey.ScrollBars   := ssVertical;
   FEditFTPPrivateKey.Hint         := sReadOnlyButPaste;
   
   inherited;
end;


This is a Delphi 12 64-bits app
Assigned(FEditFTPPrivateKey.OnKeyPress) is true at the end of the FormCreate


Do you want to respond to key presses in popup editor? If so, you have to handle Properties.OnPopup, cast Properties.PopupControl to TcxMemo and assign it's OnKeyPress handler.

@BrakNicku That might be it. I already saw in the TcxDBBlobEdit hierarchy that there's a pop up editor somewhere. My test app before implementing this used a TDBMemo, IIRC there's no popup involved there.

@AndreasRejbrand  I have edited the question with a procedure KeyPress in the TPasswordTcxDBBlobEdit

BrakNicku's comment did the trick:
Inheritance is
TcxDBBlobEdit - > TcxCustomBlobEdit -> TcxCustomPopUpEdit
It is a popup editor of type (Tcx)Memo and that needs the OnKeypress handler.
Working code is now:
type
  TPasswordTcxDBBlobEdit = class(TcxDBBlobEdit)
  private
     procedure SetPasswordMode(const Value: Boolean);
     procedure MemoKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  protected
     FPasswordMode : Boolean;
     FPasswordChar : Char;
     FPrivateKeyFld: String;
     procedure WMPaste(var Message: TWMPaste); message WM_PASTE;
  public
     property PasswordMode: Boolean read FPasswordMode write SetPasswordMode;
     property PasswordChar: Char write FPasswordChar;
     property PrivateKeyFld: String write FPrivateKeyFld;
     constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
     procedure PropertiesPopup(Sender: TObject);
  end;

procedure TPasswordTcxDBBlobEdit.PropertiesPopup(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ((Sender as TcxDBBlobEdit).Properties.PopupControl as TcxPopupMemo).OnKeyPress := MemoKeyPress;
   inherited;
end;

procedure TPasswordTcxDBBlobEdit.MemoKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
   lCtrl,
   lShift,
   lPaste: Boolean;
begin
   if not FPasswordMode then Exit;  // Alles toegestaan
   lCtrl  := (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0); // High bit set
   lShift := (GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0);
   lPaste := lCtrl and ((Key = 'V') or (Key = 'v') or (Key = #$16))   // #$16 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78928063/weird-16-value-for-v-character-in-onkeypress
             or
             lShift and (GetKeyState(VK_INSERT) < 0);
   if not lPaste then
      Key := #0;

  inherited;
end;

(Updated title and added DevExpress tag to the question because this is relevant)
